# How can I do string interpolation on smartpy?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, error, string

I'm trying to provide better error messages. I've tried several things already that don't work such as regular python fstrings, regular string concatenation. I'm tried to using the `sp.string` function now, but it still doesn't work.

Example:

```
x_i = (sp.to_int(params.x + i))
y_j = (sp.to_int(params.y + j))
err_msg = "contains pixel(" + sp.string(x_i) + ") that has been bought already"
sp.failwith(err_msg)
```

Error message when running it:

```
Error: Error in Scenario
Literal format error: (string(toInt(add(attr(params 48)x 57)(iter i 55)58)58))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to cast an int to a string in Michelson.

I recommend you to have static error messages, such as:

```
class Errors:
  SOME_ERROR = "SOME_ERROR"

# some contract
class Contract(sp.Contract):
  ...

  x_i = (sp.to_int(params.x + I))
  y_j = (sp.to_int(params.y + j))
  sp.failwith(Errors.SOME_ERROR)
```

SmartPy also gives you the option to define the [exception verbosity](https://smartpy.io/reference.html#_exception_optimization_levels).

Comment: Failing is possible on a non constant as well such as: `sp.failwith(("contains pixel", x_i, "that has been bought already"))`. It should also provide all the necessary data (but it will take a lot of place).

Comment: Also, `sp.string` is for string literals, aka, constants.

Comment: @FFF passing in that tuple worked! (Feel free to write that as a separate answer and I can mark it as accepted)

What do you mean it will take a lot of place?

Comment: Strings are major culprits for storage taken by smart contracts. You may not care for a small contract but it’s important for bigger ones when you do this repeatedly (this is the reason why SmartPy compiles location error as the line number only).

Answer (score 1):

```
def string_of_nat(params):
    c   = sp.map({x : str(x) for x in range(0, 10)})
    x   = sp.local('x', params)
    res = sp.local('res', [])
    sp.if x.value == 0:
        res.value.push('0')
    sp.while 0 < x.value:
        res.value.push(c[x.value % 10])
        x.value //= 10
    return sp.concat(res.value)
```

ref: https://smartpy.io/releases/20210118-6f466eee56038df8fda8b2f77819b83398346296/ide?template=stringManipulations.py